# playframework 2.0 using form data outside of a form

Tags: forms, input, get, playframework-2.0

I have a form. One of the input fields I use is a link, another is a description.

```
@inputText(dealForm("link"), '_label -> "Web Link")
@inputText(dealForm("desc"), '_label -> "Description")
```

All works well for the form.

Now I want to split the page by a table row, so the left side contains the form. I want to show the web page to the right (in a iframe) that the value link in the form points to. I am not sure how to access the form data for "link" for use in a iframe.

I tried the following

```
 1) iframe width="800"  height="600" src="request.dealForm.get("link")"

 2) iframe width="800"  height="600" src="dealForm.get("link")"
```

I get the following error

> For request 'GET /deals/request.dealForm.get(' [Cannot parse parameter id as Long: For input string: "request.dealForm.get("]

I am new to play framework, any help here will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In Play's view both of those should work:

```
src='dealForm("link").value'
src='dealForm.field("link").value'
```

Additionally you can probably use JavaScript (and ie. jQuery) to load other page via AJAX to some `DIV` without reloading the whole page after changes in the `link` field.

Comment: Thanks @biesior; I tried both formats.  <iframe  src="dealForm.field("link").value"></iframe>. I get the error - -For request 'GET /deals/dealForm.field(' [Cannot parse parameter id as Long: For input string: "dealForm.field("]